# Log4javascript - Log into a file using AjaxAppender in javascript (not node)

Tags: javascript, log4javascript

I am using [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org) and I created an appender that logs my javascript code in the log4js console. I want to change it, and log everything into a file. I tried the examples I found online, but I couldn't actually find a valid way of writing the logs into a txt file. I am **USING** log4js file - as reference to log4js ( **log4javascript.js**
[downloaded from here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/log4javascript/)), not using the node module or other way of injecting it.

Here's my appender:

```
var log = log4javascript.getDefaultLogger();
var ajaxAppender = new log4javascript.AjaxAppender(url);
var jsonLayout = new log4javascript.JsonLayout();
ajaxAppender.setLayout(jsonLayout);
log.addAppender(ajaxAppender);
log.info("Hello World");
```

So, how I can log the info in a file? Also, The url is my domain. Is it right? Or I should write something else there?

Thank you in advance.